# How to pass a non-changing inline object as component prop and not force a re-render

Tags: react-native

We have a composite component, called `<AppTextInput>`. It wraps a regular `react-native` `<TextInput>` to implement some pretty animations and a custom placeholder. In order for the inner `<TextInput>` to be customizable from the outside the `<AppTextInput>` exposes an `inputProps` prop which is used like so:

```
<AppTextInput
  inputProps={{
      onChangeText: this.onChangeName,
      autoCorrect: false,
      defaultValue: this.props.userData.fullname,
  }}
/>
```

And inside of `<AppTextInput>` the props are passed like so:

```
render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <TextInput
              {...inputProps}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

*I've ommited the complexity of the real `<AppTextInput>` to keep things simple.*

Now whenever I use the `<AppTextInput>` inside of another component it re-renders whenever the parent component re-renders. It happens even if I pass an empty object

```
<AppTextInput inputProps={{}} />
```

This is logical since, even though the values of the passed object did not change a brand new object was made, thus the shallow comparison fails and `<AppTextInput>` thinks it has received a changed prop.

There are a couple of workarounds to this I can think of:

- implementing our own `shouldComponentUpdate()`, but it could potentially cause future fails if the comparison is not updated properly;
- pass the input props one by one and not as part of an object, but the dynamic prop feature is a really nice thing to have and already used in several places.

Is there a clever third option that we are not seeing here? One where we would be able to pass the props as a composite object but a re-render will  not fire if the values of the object have not changed. Maybe some kind of a trick where the props are defined as an object, but not inline and the object is recreated if we need to change a prop.

Comment: Could you please provide the implementation of your onChangeName function?

Comment: Does it really matter? It's a prop of the parent component coming from it's parent component. And as I said, even if I pass an empty object `{{}}` as inputProps, the `<AppTextInput>` re-renders on every parent component re-render. So I think it's not related to the concrete implementation of the function.